# How can I style the n-th div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have design like this :

```
<body id="layout">
 <div id="section-header">
   <div class="widget" id="Pagelist1">
    <div class="widget-wrap1">
     <div class="widget-wrap2">
        <div class="widget-content">
        </div>
     </div> 
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="widget" id="Pagelist2">
    <div class="widget-wrap1">
     <div class="widget-wrap2">
        <div class="widget-content">
        </div>
     </div> 
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Requirement: CSS always start with `body#layout`
How can I style for `widget-content` class (child of `Pagelist2` ID)?
I tried styling like this but its not working: 
`body#layout > #Pagelist2 > .widget-content {....}`

I want to style the class `.widget-content`

Comment: Oh.sorry. it's my mistake of my post.

Comment: Ok, Your answers are already available below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
#layout  #Pagelist2 .widget-content {....}
```

or just

```
#Pagelist2 .widget-content {....}
```

It wasn't working for you because you were using the child selector and `#Pagelist2` isn't an immediate child of the body.

Comment: oh.that is right. I learned a new knowledge from yours. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Worth noting that this selector 'space' is called the 'descendent selector' meaning it will apply to all matches that are contained in an element, and not just a direct child

Answer (score 2):

```
body#layout > #Pagelist2 > .widget-content {....}
```

This not work because of ">": it means that #Pagelist2 has to be directly children of body#layout.

```
body#layout #Pagelist2 .widget-content {...}
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) `>`.

```
body#layout > #Pagelist2 > .widget-content
```

Soo your CSS sets the style of all `.widget-content` elements that are immediate children of `#Pagelist2` who is immediate children of `body#layout`, but you dont have this chain on your HTML markup.

The selector who you want is

```
#Pagelist2 .widget-content {...}
```

> But where is my `body#layout` ?

You dont need it because your page can only have **ONE** `#Pagelist2` to be valid, as you can see in the [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) spec.

Comment: body#layout is necessary because it is just for Home Layout in Blogger. Thanks for your help. I highly appreciate all suggestions and yours.

Comment: Highly recomend you to change that to a class and not id. Id's have higher specificity, soo use then carefully

Answer (score -1):

'>' isn't fully supported by some older browsers. So you can drop that.

You might want to specify the full path of the structure.

```
body#layout #Pagelist2 .widget-wrap1 .widget-wrap1 .widget-content
```

Or simplify it

```
#Pagelist2 .widget-content
```

Comment: `>` is supported back to ie7. that's not the reason to get rid of it, it's because he's looking for the descendent selector, not the child selector